# Trying to avoid multicollinearity in lme models with categorical factors and a continuous covariate

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, multicollinearity

I would like to examine the effects of categorical factors A and B (say, one with levels A1, A2, and A3, and the other with levels B1 and B2) and their interaction as fixed effects in a mixed effects linear model. Additionally, I would like to account for the effect of a continuous covariate C. However, I know from the start that A and B (maybe also A:B) predict C reasonably well. Is it still possible to obtain a model that appropriately accounts for the effects of A and B controlling for C (or, more specifically, that part of C that is not related to A/B)?
What comes to my mind is something like (in `lme4` language)

a) entering the residuals of a linear model in which A and B are predictors of C
as fixed effect in the `lme` model:

```
lmer(dv~A\*B+residuals(lm(C~A\*B))+(1|random_effect))
```

OR

b) use as a new dependent variable the residuals of a model predicting the original dv from C.

```
lmer( 
     residuals(lmer(dv~C+(1|random_effect))) ~ A\*B+(1|random_effect)
     )
```

Are these approaches appropriate?